# Factorize a number and check prime of the sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

The exercise was:

> Design a program that finds all numbers from 1 to 1000 whose prime factors, when added together, sum up to a prime number (for example, 12 has prime factors of 2, 2, and 3, which sum to 7, which is prime). Implement the code for that algorithm.

I am supposed to use very basics of C++ including `else/if, while and for loops`, and of course declaring some functions.

Regardless of the smaller cases like 2, 3, 5. I still don't get the right output. The output was:

```
6 (sum of factors is 5 : OK)
8 (sum of factors is 6 : WRONG)
10 (sum of factors is 7: OK)
12 (sum of factors is 7: OK)
14 (sum of factors is 9: WRONG)
15 (sum of factors is 8: SO WRONG..)
```

etc..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

bool CheckPrime (int x)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
    {
        if( x%i==0 )
        {count++;}
    }
    if ( count==2 )
    {return true;}
    else
    {return false;}

}

int MakeSum (int x)
{
    int Sum = 0;
    for (double i=2; i<sqrt(x); i++)
    {
        if (CheckPrime(i))
        {
            for (double j=1; j<1000; j++)
            {
                int k = pow( i, j);
                if ( (x % k) == 0 )
                {
                    Sum = Sum + i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Sum;
}

int main() // Output cac so tim dc.
{
    int SUM = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        SUM = MakeSum(i);
        if (CheckPrime(SUM))
        {
            cout << i << '\n';
            SUM = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (double i=2; i<sqrt(x); i++)` You never consider primes larger than the square root. That's something that makes it wrong. `for (double j=1; j<1000; j++) { int k = pow(i, j);` That's another thing. That overflows big time.

Comment: Can you explain why the numbers for 8, 14, and 15 are marked wrong?  I think 6,9,8 are correct, not wrong, because I get a result [5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 8] from python statement `[f(j,2) for j in (6,8,10,12,14,15)]` where f is given by `def f(w,p): return 0 if w<2 else (f(w,p+1) if w%p else p+f(w/p,p))`.

Comment: @jwpat7 They are marked wrong because they should not be part of the output (the sum is not prime).

Comment: @Marc, oh, right.  Then I should have said something like `d=xrange(2,501); p=[2,3]+[x for x in d if 1==pow(2,x-1,x)==pow(3,x-1,x)]; print [j for j in d if f(j,2) in p]` (which produces `[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 22 ...  487, 488, 491, 499, 500]` but unfortunately `f()` recurses too deeply if 501 is replaced by 1001).

Answer (score 0):

How about this for makesum function?

```
makesum(int k)
{
int i;
if(checkprime(k))
{
    return k;
}
for(i=2;i<=(k/2);i++)
{
    if(k%i==0 && checkprime(i))
    {
        int y=k/i;
        sum=i+makesum(y);
    }
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Take `x=8`, which is 2^3. With this code, sum would be 2 instead of 6.

Comment: @MarcClaesen 3*17 = 51. :)

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out @WillNess! My rule was for the smallest prime factor :( The posted code would still give `SUM=2` for `x=8`, because the primes that get tested are 2, 3 and 5 (of which only 2 is a factor). You forget the fact you have `CheckPrime` inside the loop.

Comment: @MarcClaesen but your instincts were right, you certainly do not need to test up to `x/2`. `sqrt(x)` *is* enough - when you divide the new found smallest factor out of the number being factorized.

Comment: if 12 is the number you have to check, then why are you adding 2 twice? the factors of 12 are {1,2,3,4,6,12} so the prime factors are {2,3} and the sum is 5. Right?

Comment: Yes, but I was still overly hasty. Should not have made that mistake :)

Comment: @AthreyaNagaraj the OP wants to count recurring factors. 12=2*2*3, so the sum of factors (s)he is looking for is 7. This is why your code does not solve the question at hand. This is the function of the loop in `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to determine if a number is prime:

```
function isPrime(n)
    d := 2
    while d * d <= n
        if n % d == 0
            return False
        d := d + 1
    return True
```

And here is a similar function to determine the prime factors of a number:

```
function factors(n)
    f, fs := 2, []
    while f * f <= n
        if n % f == 0
            append f to fs
            n := n / f
        else f := f + 1
    append n to fs
    return fs
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to C++ and work out the loops and logic to complete the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedo-code.  First, I'll define a function that returns the smallest factor of a number other than 1, or 0 if the number is prime.

```
def FindFactor(x)
  for i from 2 to sqrt(x)
    if x%i==0
      return i
  return 0
```

Now, we can very easily check whether a number is prime.  This is useful in your main method.

```
def CheckPrime(x)
  return !FindFactor(x)
```

Finally, we do the sum calculation.  The advantage of doing it recursively is that it is very easy to get some speed advantages by caching smaller results:

```
def MakeSum(x)
  factor1 = FindFactor(x)
  if !factor1
    return x
  factor2 = x / factor1
  return factor1 + MakeSum(factor2)
```

In each call of `MakeSum`, we find the number's smallest factor.  If it is prime, return the number itself.  Otherwise, recurse on the smallest factor and the original number divided by the smallest factor.

Actually, since we know the smallest factor is already prime, I didn't bother recursing on it.  This turns it into tail-call recursion, so we don't have to worry about stack depth, assuming a reasonable compiler.